# context.executeQueryAsync always fail

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

context.executeQueryAsync it woked fine before with no problem and suddenly still always fail i don't know what are the reasons:

```
  <Sharepoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="SP.js" Localizable="false"  ID="s3"   
     LoadAfterUI="true"/>
  <Sharepoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="SP.Core.js" Localizable="false"  
     ID="s1" LoadAfterUI="true"/>
  <Sharepoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="SP.Runtime.js" Localizable="false"  
     ID="s2" LoadAfterUI="true"/>
  <Sharepoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="SP.UI.Dialog.js" Localizable="false"  
     ID="s4" LoadAfterUI="true"/>
  <Sharepoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="CUI.js" Localizable="false"  ID="s5" 
     LoadAfterUI="true"/>
  <Sharepoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="SP.UI.Rte.js" Localizable="false"  
     ID="s6" LoadAfterUI="true"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var items;
    var web;

    function getItems2(camlQuery){

     var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     web = context.get_web();
     var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('listname');
     items = list.getItems(camlQuery, 'AllItems');

     context.load(items);
     context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataSucceeded),   
     Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed));  

     }

    function onListDataSucceeded(sender, args) {
       //...success
    }

    function onListDataFailed(sender, args) {
        //...failed
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var camlQuery = ".....";
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getItems2(camlQuery), "sp.js");

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check why it is failing. In the failed function add this line to display the error message as an alert.

```
alert('Failed: \n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
```